# How to use observable with promise and return observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I have this function to add a document to a firestore collection.

```
addListing(listing: Listing) {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      first(),
      map(user => user.uid),
      map(uid => {
        const listingId = this.afs.createId();

        this.listingsCollection.doc(listingId).set(listing);

        return listingId;
      })
    );
  }
```

This function should return an observable of the `listingId` as it does now.

However I'm not sure if I should return the `listingId` in the `...set(listing).then()` because when the listing will not be "set" or any error occurs I would not return the `listingId` but something else.

I've already tried to check how it goes:

```
addListing3(listing: Listing) {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      first(),
      map(user => user.uid),
      map(uid => {
        const listingId = this.afs.createId();

        this.listingsCollection
          .doc(listingId)
          .set(listing)
          .then(() => {
            return listingId;
          })
          .catch(error => console.error);
      })
    );
  }
```

The problem is to be honest I'm not sure how to use the promise with observable.

The first approach returns Observable of string

The seconds approach returns Observable of void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually return Promise and merge it into the Observable stream with `mergeMap`:

```
addListing3(listing: Listing): Observable<string> {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      first(),
      map(user => user.uid),
      mergeMap(uid => {
        const listingId = this.afs.createId();

        return this.listingsCollection
          .doc(listingId)
          .set(listing)
          .then(() => {
            return listingId;
          })
          .catch(error => console.error);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: I actually managed to do it other way.
`return from(promise).pipe(
          map(() => listingId),
          catchError(error => of(error))
        );`
Where the `promise` is just `this.listingsCollection.doc(listingId).set(listing)` and I can better handle errors.